# Form params are returning json instead of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to retrieve some text_input from a simple form. But the thing is when calling params[:param_name], i'm getting something like that:

```
{"{:readonly=>\"true\", :placeholder=>\"Ville\", :class=>\"form-control\"}"=>"marrakech"}
```

Knowing that all i need here is the string 'Marrakech' !

Here is the form :

`<%= form_for([@voiture, @voiture.reservations.new]) do |f| %>`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 price_tag">
        <span><%= @voiture.prix %>Dhs</span>
        <span class="pull-right">Par jour</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Nom</label>
        <%= text_field :nom, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Nom', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Prenom</label>
        <%= text_field :prenom, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Prenom', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>     
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>CIN</label>
        <%= text_field :cin, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'CIN', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Age</label>
        <%= text_field :age, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Age', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Ville</label>
        <%= text_field :ville, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Ville', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Télephone</label>
        <%= text_field :telephone, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Telephone', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Email</label>
        <%= text_field :email, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Check In</label>
        <%= f.text_field :start_date, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Start Date', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Check Out</label>
        <%= f.text_field :end_date, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'End Date', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
    </div>
</div>

<%= f.hidden_field :voiture_id, value: @voiture.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :prix, value: @voiture.prix %>
<%= f.hidden_field :total, id: 'reservation_total' %>

<h4><span id="message"></span></h4>

<div id="preview" style="display: none">
    <table class="reservation-table" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Day(s)</td>
                <td><span id="reservation_days"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><span id="reservation_sum"></span>Dhs</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
</div>

<br>
<%= f.submit "Book Now", id:"btn_book", class: "btn btn-primary wide", disabled: 'true' %>
```

And the controller :

```
def create
    @client = Client.create(nom: params[:nom],prenom: params[:prenom],cin: params[:cin],age: params[:age],ville: params[:ville],telephone: params[:telephone],email: params[:email])
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    @reservation.client = @client
    if @reservation.save
        redirect_to @reservation.voiture, notice: "Votre reservation a bien ete cree"
    else
        redirect_to @reservation.voiture, notice: "Erreur"
    end
end
```

Comment: Am beginner but are you sure, as nested, you shouldnt call something like params[:voiture][:param_name]

Comment: I'm talking about the input which aren't related to voiture actually. FOr example: <%= text_field :nom %> not <%= f.text_field :nom %>

Comment: Try replacing text_field with text_field_tag

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
f.text_field :nom
```

but all you are doing is

```
text_field :nom
```

Not too sure if you are doing this the right way but you should take a look at this [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)

And if you are attempting to save a nested form, then for your case I have done it for rather simple case.

in `clients_controller.rb`

```
  def new
    @client = Client.new
    @client.reservations.build
  end

 def create
   @client = Client.new(client_params)
   if @client.save!
     render :show, id: @client
   else
     render :new
   end
 end

  private

  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:name, reservations_attributes:    [:start_date, :end_date])
  end
```

in `client.rb`

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservations
end
```

Take note of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` here.

and in my `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :reservations do |reservation_form| %>
    <%= reservation_form.text_field :start_date %>
    <%= reservation_form.text_field :end_date %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @saad , i appreciate a lot your help, but it doesn't totally solve my problem since it's more complicated. PLASE take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779041/trying-to-make-a-form-using-nested-attributes . Thanks again !