# Trying to make a form using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a beginner in rails, so I'm quite stuck with the nested attributes.

Here is an overview of what I'm looking for:

A rentalcar can create cars.(done)

Clients can reserve a car.

Clients are created with the reservation at the same time by the rentalcar.

I'm trying to make a form for reservation which will contain both the client and the reservation information, since it will be the rentalcar who fill all the information.

It's why i need to use nested attributes, but until now I'm having some difficulties. 
I have four models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rentalcar
  has_many :photos
  has_many :reservations
end
```

.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :reservations
end
```

.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :client
 belongs_to :car
end
```

.

```
class rentalcar < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :cars
 has_many :reservations
end
```

The form :

```
<%= form_for([@car, @car.reservations.new]) do |f| %>
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 price_tag">
        <span><%= @car.price %>Dhs</span>
        <span class="pull-right">Par jour</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Nom</label>
        <%= f.text_field :nom, placeholder: 'Nom', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Prenom</label>
        <%= f.text_field :prenom, placeholder: 'Prenom', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>     
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>CIN</label>
        <%= f.text_field :cin, placeholder: 'CIN', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Age</label>
        <%= f.text_field :age, placeholder: 'Age', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Ville</label>
        <%= f.text_field :ville, placeholder: 'Ville', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Télephone</label>
        <%= f.text_field :telephone, placeholder: 'Telephone', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Email</label>
        <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
</div>

<%= f.fields_for :reservations do |reservation_form| %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Check In</label>
        <%= reservation_form.text_field :start_date, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Start Date', class: 'form-control' %>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Check Out</label>
        <%= reservation_form.text_field :end_date, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'End Date', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>        
    </div>
</div>

<%= reservation_form.hidden_field :car_id, value: @car.id %>
<%= reservation_form.hidden_field :price, value: @car.prix %>
<%= reservation_form.hidden_field :total, id: 'reservation_total' %>

<% end %>

<h4><span id="message"></span></h4>

<div id="preview" style="display: none">
    <table class="reservation-table" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Day(s)</td>
                <td><span id="reservation_days"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><span id="reservation_sum"></span>Dhs</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
</div>

<br>
<%= f.submit "Book Now", id:"btn_book", class: "btn btn-primary wide", disabled: 'true' %>
```

So the idea is to get this form after doing something like : cars/1/reservate. 
And we will have something like this in the controller:

```
def reservate
 @car = Car.find(params[:id])
 @client = Client.new
 @client.reservations.build
end
```

but i dont know in which controller it should remains

Edit1 :

Indexes :

```
add_index "reservations", ["client_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_client_id", using: :btree 

add_index "reservations", ["car_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_car_id", using: :btree 

add_index "voitures", ["rentelcar_id"], name: "index_voitures_on_rentelcar_id", using: :btree

add_foreign_key "reservations", "clients"
add_foreign_key "reservations", "cars"
add_foreign_key "cars", "rentelcars"
```

Comment: Your data model is rather confusing to me but with that said I would put the logic from your reservate action into the create action on the reservations controller. I think that is what you were asking for?

Comment: not only, is the form code correct? if yes can you please help me with the create action in the controller?

Comment: You really can't expect anyone to be able to answer "Is the form code correct" except for yourself.  What does your code do currently and what are you trying to get it to do?

Comment: Create some reservations of cars which already exist. By creating a reservation we also create the associated client. in the same form..

Comment: @Remis07 share your code on github, that would be more useful for me to look in to then. Also by doing `def reservate` you are not following restful practice, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Why do you need the rental car model? Seems redundant. Reservations takes care of join table for users and cars. If at all necessary, rental cars is better suited to inherit from cars

Comment: rentalcar represent a kind of societies which can create its cars and manage its reservations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your relationships are a bit messed up, this is how I created new relations.

```
class AddRelevantModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :car_rentals do |t|
      t.string      :name
      t.timestamps  null: false
    end

    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.string      :model
      t.string      :car_number
      t.belongs_to  :car_rental, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps  null: false
    end

    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string      :full_name
      t.integer     :age
      t.string      :email
      t.string      :phone_number
      t.timestamps  null: false
    end

    create_table :reservations do |t|
      t.belongs_to    :car, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to    :client, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.datetime      :start_date
      t.datetime      :end_date
      t.timestamps    null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`car_rental.rb`

```
class CarRental < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

`car.rb`

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :clients, through: :reservations
end
```

`reservation.rb`

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :car

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :car
end
```

`client.rb`

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :cars, through: :reservations
end
```

`reservations_controller.rb`

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @reservation.build_client
  end

  def create
    @reversation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

    if @reversation.save
      render :show, id: @reservation
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation)
    .permit(
      :start_date, :end_date, client_attributes: [:full_name, :age, :email, :phone_number]
    )
  end
end
```

`reservations/new.html.erb`

```
<h1>Reservations</h1>
<%= form_for(@reservation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :start_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :start_date %>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :end_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :end_date %>
  <br>
  <%= f.fields_for :client do |client_field| %>
    <%= client_field.label :full_name %>
    <%= client_field.text_field :full_name %>
    <br>  
    <%= client_field.label :age %>
    <%= client_field.text_field :age %>
    <br>   
    <%= client_field.label :email %>
    <%= client_field.text_field :email %>
    <br>
    <%= client_field.label :phone_number %>
    <%= client_field.text_field :phone_number %>
  <% end %>

  <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now if you submit the form you can see in your database that the client is also saved for the reservation.

```
 Reservation.first.client
  Reservation Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations"   ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Client id: 1, full_name: "remis", age: 22, email: "remis@gmail.com", phone_number: "1231331", created_at: "2016-06-13 06:28:37", updated_at: "2016-06-13 06:28:37">
```

Comment: Thanks a loot Saad, i reallly appreciate it. That helps me solve the problem!!