# Serialized fields_for not populating from db on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, populate, fields-for

On the edit page for this form all of the fields outside of the `fields_for` tag (inbox name, automatic reconciliation, and a few others not listed here) are all populating based on their corresponding db value. However, everything inside the fields_for tag are not, even though they're posting to the db just fine.

I posted :`group_member_roles` as an example but there are a few other fields inside their own other `fields_for` that are doing the same thing. It's just confusing that it will post to the db but not display on edit.

The more I read into `fields_for` the more I feel like I'm not using it correctly. It seems to be more inclined to populating db tables outside of the one your form is currently referencing, but I'm just trying to serialize data within the inbox table. When I look at the :`group_member_roles` column I want it to be an array/hash containing process true/false, action add/delete, and a string of values.

```
#_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@inbox) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :inbox_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Inbox Name" %>
  <%= f.label :automatic_reconciliation, "Turn on/off automatic reconciliation" %>
  <div class="switch small">
    <%= f.check_box :automatic_reconciliation, class: "switch-input" %>
    <label class="switch-paddle" for="inbox_automatic_reconciliation">
      <span class="show-for-sr">Automatic reconciliation</span>
      <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">On</span>
      <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">Off</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :group_member_roles do |group_member_roles| %>
  <h4>Group Member Roles</h4>
  <%= group_member_roles.label :process, "Turn On/Off Processing" %>
  <div class="switch small">
    <%= group_member_roles.check_box :process, class: "switch-input" %>
    <label class="switch-paddle" for="inbox_group_member_roles_process">
      <span class="show-for-sr">Group Member Roles Processing</span>
      <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">On</span>
      <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">Off</span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <%= group_member_roles.label :action, class: "hide" %>
  <%= group_member_roles.select :action, ["Add", "Delete"], { selected: "Add" }, { class: "hide" } %>

  <%= group_member_roles.label :values %>
  <%= group_member_roles.text_field :values, placeholder: "1234, 1337, 1986" %>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: So you mean to say that in your inbox model you can do index.group_member_roles.first.process. Can you push your code on github?

Comment: Certainly, here's a link to the branch I'm working on: https://github.com/npmdigital/ondeck/tree/s7_add_group_role_and_tag_to_inbox
Also no, I can't run first.process on it, but if I look for @index.group_member_roles[:process] it shows the string.

Comment: Since you have a nested field, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37783164/1087841, not sure if this solution would be for you but I don't think I had access to your app to look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

The fields were being stored as a hash and the field was looking for an object to populate with so I added an OpenStruct dummy object to the fields_for to make it so. If anyone can think of a better way please let me know as this is pretty ugly code.

```
  <%= f.fields_for :group_member_roles, OpenStruct.new(f.object.group_member_roles) do |group_member_roles| %>
```